# How to predefine value inside model/form in Django?

Tags: django

I'm creating simple app which allows users to create group.
When user create group it has following fields:

- name
- desc
- inviteKey - i would this field to be hidden and generate 10 characters code and then send it.

My models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    groupName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    inviteKey = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Members(models.Model):
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    groupId = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isAdmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Form:

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    groupName = forms.CharField(label='Nazwa grupy', max_length=100)
    description = forms.CharField(label='Opis', max_length=255)
    inviteKey: forms.CharField(label='Kod wstępu')

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['groupName', 'description', 'inviteKey' ]
```

View:

```
def createGroup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GroupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Group created')
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        inviteKey = generateInviteKey()
        form = GroupForm(initial={'inviteKey': inviteKey})

    return render(request, 'group/createGroup.html',{'form': form})
```

Now i have form and inviteKey is visible and editable. I want this key to be visible but not editable.

[image: Form]

Comment: The problem is that if you make it disabled, upon submitting the form, it will generate a new key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that my opinion is to set the default value for your invitation key in your **model**, that way, token is created "in the background" with a unique key, but we can go further.

For example :

```
import uuid
token = models.UUIDField(
    default=uuid.uuid4,
    unique=True,
    editable=False,
)
```

This way you are sure that the token **is unique** (UUID is unique by design, but still) you cannot edit it so no wrong token can occur and last of all each object will get a unique token with no work on your side.

I am using UUID because it is recommended by Django as per the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) for token and unique identifier.

**Note :** If  you set the UUID with a default value, you cannot get it before the object is created, depending on your use you might want to set it in the form (see answer below).

Comment: Your solutions is very good, but how i can populate predefined key in user's form?

Comment: That's the good thing, **you don't have to do it**, because it will be generated for you when the object is created. 
So whenever a user create a group (or you) the token will be generated. 
You can try it by yourself from the admin panel, try creating a new group, the token will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the field disabled, so:

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    groupName = forms.CharField(label='Nazwa grupy', max_length=100)
    description = forms.CharField(label='Opis', max_length=255)
    inviteKey = forms.CharField(label='Kod wstępu', disabled=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['groupName', 'description', 'inviteKey' ]
```

This will also prevent a user from fabricating a POST request that contains a different invite key.

A problem that one now has to solve however is that we do not want to generate a different `inviteKey` when the user submits the form. This can be handled with session data, although it is not a very elegant solution. In that case we thus change the view to:

```
def createGroup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'inviteKey' in request.session:
        inviteKey = request.session['inviteKey']
        form = GroupForm(request.POST, initial={'inviteKey': inviteKey})
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Group created')
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        request.session['inviteKey'] = inviteKey = generateInviteKey()
        form = GroupForm(initial={'inviteKey': inviteKey})

    return render(request, 'group/createGroup.html',{'form': form})
```

You probably alo might want to make your `inviteKey` field unique, to prevent creating multiple groups with the same `inviteKey`:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    groupName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    inviteKey = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

Comment: Don't you think my solution works better in the sense that the author want in fact something very similar to an UUID ? Django do provide the field for it and a good description on how to set it with default value https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

Comment: @GaëtanGR: well the exact format is not that relevant: one can easily trade a generated string for a UUID. What is more problematic is that the form needs to show the "picked" string/UUID at the moment that it is not yet materialized in the database. It thus needs to persist it between the GET request and the POST request. Personally I don't really follow why to show the link at all, but with the given constraints, one needs to make use of some persistent storage.

Comment: Nice catch, in that sense I will edit my answer to reflect your input.